# Sql tuning using table and view

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a big performance problem with the following query. And need help to make it as fast as possible.

`VIEW_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE` got 2 million rows and I'm sure that I can make a better query to speed this. The application is taking almost 2 minutes to run.

```
SELECT O.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
  FROM ORDER_RELEASE O, ORDER_RELEASE_STATUS S
  WHERE O.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = S.ORDER_RELEASE_GID
   AND S.STATUS_TYPE_GID = 'STATUS'
   AND S.STATUS_VALUE_GID IN ('OPEN', 'OPEN-HANDLE')
   AND O.SOURCE_LOCATION_GID = '114'
   AND O.ORDER_RELEASE_GID NOT IN
    (SELECT V.ORDER_RELEASE_GID FROM VIEW_SHIPMENT_ORDER_RELEASE V
     WHERE V.ORDER_RELEASE_GID = O.ORDER_RELEASE_GID)
```

Here's the view code:

```
create or replace view glogowner.view_shipment_order_release as
select distinct shp.perspective, shp.shipment_gid, ssul.order_release_gid
from  shipment shp,
    shipment_s_equipment_join ssej,
    s_equipment_s_ship_unit_join sessuj,
    s_ship_unit_line ssul
where   shp.shipment_gid = ssej.shipment_gid
and     ssej.s_equipment_gid = sessuj.s_equipment_gid
and     sessuj.s_ship_unit_gid = ssul.s_ship_unit_gid
and     ssul.order_release_gid is not null
```

The explain plan:

```
1   Plan hash value: 1257125198
2    
3   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4   | Id  | Operation                          | Name                           | Rows  | Bytes |TempSpc| Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Inst   |
5   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
6   |   0 | SELECT STATEMENT REMOTE            |                                |   314 | 98596 |       | 35795   (1)| 00:07:10 |        |
7   |   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                      |                                |       |       |       |            |          |        |
8   |   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                     |                                |   314 | 98596 |       | 35795   (1)| 00:07:10 |        |
9   |*  3 |    HASH JOIN ANTI                  |                                |   201 | 48441 |       | 35192   (1)| 00:07:03 |        |
10  |   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID    | ORDER_RELEASE                  | 20104 |   726K|       |  3893   (1)| 00:00:47 | ABC123 |
11  |*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN              | OR_SOURCE_LOCATION_GID         | 20104 |       |       |   157   (0)| 00:00:02 | ABC123 |
12  |   6 |     VIEW                           | VW_SQ_1                        |  1515K|   294M|       | 31293   (1)| 00:06:16 | ABC123 |
13  |*  7 |      HASH JOIN                     |                                |  1515K|   144M|       | 31293   (1)| 00:06:16 |        |
14  |   8 |       INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN | IND_SSEJ_SEQUIPGID             | 69218 |   811K|       |    91   (0)| 00:00:02 | ABC123 |
15  |*  9 |       HASH JOIN                    |                                |  1515K|   127M|    73M| 31195   (1)| 00:06:15 |        |
16  |  10 |        INDEX STORAGE FAST FULL SCAN| PK_S_EQUIPMENT_S_SHIP_UNIT_JOI |  1515K|    56M|       |  3958   (1)| 00:00:48 | ABC123 |
17  |* 11 |        TABLE ACCESS STORAGE FULL   | S_SHIP_UNIT_LINE               |  1619K|    75M|       | 18893   (1)| 00:03:47 | ABC123 |
18  |* 12 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN               | PK_ORDER_RELEASE_STATUS        |     1 |       |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 | ABC123 |
19  |* 13 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID      | ORDER_RELEASE_STATUS           |     2 |   146 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 | ABC123 |
20  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
21   
22  Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
23  ---------------------------------------------------
24   
25     3 - access("A2"."ORDER_RELEASE_GID"="ORDER_RELEASE_GID")
26     5 - access("A2"."SOURCE_LOCATION_GID"='114')
27     7 - access("SSEJ"."S_EQUIPMENT_GID"="SESSUJ"."S_EQUIPMENT_GID")
28     9 - access("SESSUJ"."S_SHIP_UNIT_GID"="SSUL"."S_SHIP_UNIT_GID")
29    11 - storage("SSUL"."ORDER_RELEASE_GID" IS NOT NULL)
30         filter("SSUL"."ORDER_RELEASE_GID" IS NOT NULL)
31    12 - access("A2"."ORDER_RELEASE_GID"="A1"."ORDER_RELEASE_GID" AND "A1"."STATUS_TYPE_GID"='STATUS')
32    13 - filter("A1"."STATUS_VALUE_GID"='OPEN' OR "A1"."STATUS_VALUE_GID"='OPEN-HANDLE')
```

Comment: What are the schemas, indexes and [`EXPLAIN PLAN`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96533/ex_plan.htm)?

Comment: If that's a view then it's just a query that probably gets merged into the main query. No way of telling without knowing the definition of the view or the explain plan for the whole query.

Comment: I don;t know about ORacle, but in SQL Server views that call other views are notoriously slow. I would look at seeing if I could write it in such a way as to not use the other view. Also in SQL Server Not Exists is faster, that could be true in Oracle as well. And please please stop using implict joins they are a SQL antipattern.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, Just added the view.. It helps ? I'm sorry for this missing information.

Comment: i think the explain plan will be required - then other comments would be based on that.

Comment: How long does it take to execute that view query,up to the return of the last row? Is that distinct actually required?

Comment: @HLGEM Those concerns do not generally apply to Oracle.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, and others explain plan added.

Comment: @DavidAldridge this view is used everywhere.. I think that its needed because the fields may get duplicates if the user undo any planned shipment.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, that's why I put this in a comment and not as an answer.  However implict joins are a SQL antipattern in ALL databases as they are much more likely to have an acidental cross join and are harder to maintain when adding left joins etc. There is no reason except using an older database that doesn't accept joins to ever wriute an implit join.

Comment: @HLGEM well I have to disagree again I'm afraid. they have meaning that is semantically different to a join, while allowing the optimiser to convert them to a join for the actual execution plan. EXISTS in particular can also be implemented more efficiently than the outer join that people sometimes use in its place, as it can be transformed to a semi-join.

Comment: Your `ssul.order_release_gid is not null` seems to be taking some time. You may be running into the problem that Oracle doesn't index nulls. Maybe it would do better with a function-based index as suggested in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9209635/how-to-index-on-a-column-for-is-not-null-query-in-oracle/9210928#9210928)

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure that the following are indexed:

```
shipment.shipment_gid
shipment_s_equipment_join.s_equipment_gid
s_equipment_s_ship_unit_join.s_ship_unit_gid
s_ship_unit_line.order_release_gid
```

The NOT IN might work better as a NOT EXISTS.